# ¿Cómo deberían ajustarse los pronombres de manera adecuada en el verso "... y sobre yo mi sombrero"?

Tags: pronombres, letras-de-canciones

*Galerón llanero* es una canción popular del oriente colombiano que en una de sus estrofas dice:

> Sobre los llanos la palma,
>
> sobre la palma los cielos,
>
> sobre mi caballo yo
>
> y sobre yo mi sombrero.

En el último verso, ¿cómo deberían ajustarse los pronombres de manera adecuada?

Comment: ¿Quieres preguntar qué se debe usar en vez del «yo» normativamente?

Comment: en efecto, como quedaría ese último verso en prosa

Comment: Sería "sobre mí"

Comment: Además, debería haber comas entre los dos sintagmas nominales de cada verso, ya que el verbo está elidido (*sobre los llanos, la palma*, etc.) Lo correcto, como dice @blonfu, es *sobre mí, mi sombrero*; pero creo que podemos aceptar el uso de *yo* en el último verso como licencia poética, ya que busca repetir el *yo* del verso anterior.

Comment: @Carlos no acabo de entender [tu revisión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/22475/revisions). El DPD en [_puntos suspensivos_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=c5GublcDAD6kWvCUUy) dice que _Se escriben siempre pegados a la palabra o el signo que los precede, y separados por un espacio de la palabra o el signo que los sigue_, aunque lo mismo me estoy dejando algo.

Comment: @fedorqui tienes razón, aunque el texto a tener en cuenta es este: "Si se quiere dejar claro que la reproducción de una cita textual no se hace desde el comienzo mismo del enunciado, es posible escribir puntos suspensivos al inicio de la cita, sin paréntesis ni corchetes, dejando un blanco de separación respecto de la palabra a la que preceden." Es de esas cosas que pensaba que sabía pero que no es así. Lo vuelvo a dejar como estaba.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo anda, pues es interesante saber que los paréntesis son opcionales en casos así. Siempre acabamos aprendiendo algo. jeje.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En prosa o en verso, la forma gramaticalmente correcta de la última proposición sería

> *y sobre mí mi sombrero.*

Esto es así debido a que detrás de las preposiciones los pronombres personales van en la forma objeto tónica: *mí, ti, él, ella, ello, sí, nosotros/as, vosotros/as, ustedes, ellos/ellas* (en el caso de *con*, por un accidente histórico se escribe *conmigo, contigo, consigo*).

Imagino que en la canción se usa *yo*, aunque esté gramaticalmente mal, para repetir el *yo* del verso anterior. (En la poesía y la canción se permiten muchas veces licencias de esta clase.)

Comment: creo que el yo viene más por evitar una seudo-redundancia (trata de pronunciar la frase y suena raro) pero al leerla, con el acento en el primer mí ya se hace comprensible